# React-Router v4: exact statement doesn't add active class to navigation item

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm restoring a old project and I was forced to update all libraries. So of a updates I'm getting some additional problems - what was working now has stopped working.

One of these problems is an `active` class/state in navigation. Earlier `active` class was added  scrolling down the website to an appropriate section, now it's ignored. Probably something has changed in a libraries.

This navbar code is complicated but was created to maintain multi language support and be translatable with the help of a `i18next` library.

`React router and router-dom is 4.3.1`

So, here it is :

**Navigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Nav from './houses/Nav.js';

var navbar = {};
navbar.brand = { linkTo: "#hero", text: "WEB sprendimai" };
navbar.links = [
  { linkTo: "#", event: "lt", spanClassName: "flag-icon flag-icon-lt" },
  { linkTo: "#", event: "en", spanClassName: "flag-icon flag-icon-gb" },
  { linkTo: "#about", text: "About", spanClassName: "btnicon icon-user" },
  { linkTo: "#services", text: "Servives", spanClassName: "btnicon icon-cup" },
  { linkTo: "#contacts", text: "Kontaktai", spanClassName: "btnicon icon-envelope-open" }
];

class Navigation extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <div className="container">
          <Nav {...navbar} />
        </div>
      </header>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Navigation;
```

and **Nav.js**

```
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

class Nav extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-custom py-1" role="navigation">
        <div className="container">
        <NavBrand linkTo={this.props.brand.linkTo} text={t(this.props.brand.text)} />
            <button type="button" className="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-label={t('Perjungti navigaciją')}>
              <span className="sr-only">{t('Perjungti navigaciją')}</span>
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>            
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <NavMenuExt links={this.props.links} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
};

class NavBrand extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <a className="navbar-brand" alt="back to home" href={this.props.linkTo}>{this.props.text}
        <span className="brandicon"></span>
        <span className="brandname">&lt;&nbsp;K&nbsp;&gt;</span>
      </a>
    );
  }
};

class NavMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    var links = this.props.links.map(function (link, index) {
      return (
        <NavLinkExtCreator key={index} linkTo={link.linkTo} text={t(link.text)} active={link.active} event={link.event} spanClassName={link.spanClassName} />
      );

    });
    return (
      <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        {links}
      </ul>
    );
  }
};

class NavLinkCreator extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { i18n } = this.props;
    const toggle = lng => i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
        
console.log(this.props.event);
    if (this.props.event) {

      return (
        <li className="nav-item"><NavLink className="nav-link" onClick={() => toggle(this.props.event)} to={'/' + this.props.event}><span className={(this.props.spanClassName)}></span></NavLink></li>
      )
    }

    return (
      <li className="nav-item"><NavLink className="nav-link" to={this.props.linkTo} exact activeClassName="active">{this.props.text}<span className={(this.props.spanClassName)}></span></NavLink></li>
    );
  }
};

const NavExt = withTranslation()(Nav);
const NavMenuExt = withTranslation()(NavMenu);
const NavLinkExtCreator = withTranslation()(NavLinkCreator);

export {
  NavMenuExt,
  NavLinkExtCreator
}

export default NavExt;
```

Could someone help me out to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that it's a bug of a `4.3.1` version.
I had to downgrade `react-router-dom` to 4.2.2